# How do I give specific users access to specific websites in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I'm building a login system. My database looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuFOI.png)

Lets say, after loggin in, the code recognizes who is currently logged in and sends them to a specific website, based on the content in their KURS field.

So user yyy would be send to lets say TG111.php
And user uuu would be send to lets say TG112.php
**TG111.php looks like this**

```php
<?php
session_start();

    $sess = $_SESSION['KURS'];

    if ($sess !== 'TG111') {
      if ($sess !== 'TG112') {
        if ($sess !== 'TG113') {
          header("Location: index.php");
          exit();
        }
        else {
          header("Location: TG113.php");
          exit();
        }
      }
      else {
        header("Location: TG112.php");
        exit();
      }
    }
    else {
      header('Location: TG111.php');
      exit();
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a href="logout.php">Abmelden</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**But this doesn't work...**

Comment: Try setting `$_SESSION['KURS']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for? but you can try to debug it to see what the problem, you can try using this in your if statement

```
if($sess == 'TG111') {
    header('Location: TG111.php');
    exit();
} elseif ($sess == 'TG112') {
    header("Location: TG112.php");
    exit();
} elseif ($sess == 'TG113') {
    header("Location: TG113.php");
    exit();
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```